# keep file dialog open even after displaying alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI Guys,

I have the below code where I check for the file types of the file selected.
`hiddenFileInputFile` is of file input type.
Below code is working fine but if the user does not supply a `.csv` file then it show the alert, which is fine, but then I want the file dialog to remain open which is not happening.

Please advise.
Also is there any way where I can apply the filter directly to the file dialog to select only `.csv` files using jquery/javascript?

```
Element.find('input.hiddenFileInputFile').change(function () 
{
            var filename = $(this).val();
            if (!/\.csv$/.test(filename)) {
                alert('Please select a csv file');
                return false;
            }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke its `click` event after the alert:

```
if (!/\.csv$/.test(filename)) {
   alert('Please select a csv file');
   $(this).click();
   return false;
}
```

This will not "keep it open" which is not possible, but re-open it when the file is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't externally trigger the file input click event for security reasons. However if you want to restrict the user on the client side you can try:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/csv" />
```

This will only make the .csv type files visible in the open file dialog. However I would put a control on the server side as well. If not the correct type you can open an alert dialog and style the file input accordingly (e.g. red border) and let the user to open the file dialog because there isn't any way for you to trigger that.

There are ways provided by some plugins for jquery which give you a lot of control on the uploading process.

[Jquery plugin 1](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/),
[uploadify jquery](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/fileext/)

to name a few.

Hope it helps.